# How to keep values after changing chained selectInputs in shiny in R?

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I have a complicated shiny app (here is a simpler example) which looks like that:

[image]

The app gives user the possibility to change four parameters (`selectInput`). The lower parameter depends on the highter one (ex. `month` on `year`, `type` on `year` and `month` and so on). Everything works but the fact that when I change one parameter, the other one changes too. It is needed in some situations, but not always. It is needed when the level chosen earlier does not exist in new configuration but for example when I have the following situation it should not be changed. Ex. I chose type `'AGD'` and `size` `'medium'` for some `year` and `month` and I show the prise or something for this combination. Then I would like to compare it to the same `size` in `type` `'RTV'` so I change `type` parameter. Everything works but the `size` changes to the `'big'` while I wanted it still to be `'medium'`. I can make another click but what for? It is very inconvenient then...

Do you know how to deal with a problem like that?

I managed to do it for two dependencies using `observe` and `reactive values`, but for four dependencies it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

data <- data.frame(year = rep(c(rep(2018, 6), rep(2019, 11)), each = 5),
                   month = rep(c(7:12, 1:11), each = 5),
                   type = rep(c("AGD", "AGD", "AGD", "RTV", "RTV"), 6 + 11),
                   value = sample(1:100, 85),
                   size = rep(c("big", "small", "medium", "big", "miedium"), 6 + 11))

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(

            uiOutput("year"),
            uiOutput("month"),
            uiOutput("type"),
            uiOutput("size")

        ),

        mainPanel(

        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$year <- renderUI({

        year <- data %>%
            select(year) %>%
            unique()

        selectInput("year",
                    "YEAR",
                    year$year,
                    selected = max(year$year))

    })

    output$month <- renderUI({

        month <- data %>%
            filter(year == input$year) %>%
            select(month) %>%
            unique() %>%
            arrange()

        selectInput("month",
                    "MONTH",
                    month$month,
                    selected = max(month$month))

    })

    output$type <- renderUI({

        type <- data %>%
            filter(year == input$year,
                   month == input$month) %>%
            select(type) %>%
            unique() %>%
            arrange()

        selectInput("type",
                    "TYPE",
                    type$type,
                    selected = type$type[1])

    })

    output$size <- renderUI({

        size <- data %>%
            filter(year == input$year,
                   month == input$month,
                   type == input$type) %>%
            select(size) %>%
            unique() %>%
            arrange()

        selectInput("size",
                    "SIZE",
                    size$size,
                    selected = size$size[1])

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues With the Existing Code

There are a couple of issues with the code here and the solution allows us to introduce the concept of memory into the app. First and foremost there are two issues I would like to address right off the bat.

1. `c("big", "small", "medium", "big", "medium")` and not `c("big", "small", "medium", "big", "miedium")`
2. The `uiOutput()` and `renderUI()` combination results the server serving a **new** `selectInput` button, everytime the input is changed. Instead we can simply instantiate a static UI element and update it using `updateSelectInput()`

### Solution

To solve this problem lets first fix 1) and 2) described above. Then we need to introduce the concept of memory. The server needs to know what was previously selected, so that we can set it as the default option when the `selectInput` is updated. We can store this as a regular list (a variable for year, month, type and size) or a reactive list using `reactiveValues`.

Its great that you have settled on a clear cut logic for the filtering options, there is a clear hierarchy from years-> months -> type -> size. However, everytime `months` was changed for example a new input was generated for `type` and `size`.

We would now like to introduce a simple logic where the input selection only modifies the memory `selected_vals`. Then a change in memory triggers the other inputs to be updated. This is best seen in the solution below.

### Code Solution

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

data <- data.frame(year = rep(c(rep(2018, 6), rep(2019, 11)), each = 5),
                   month = rep(c(7:12, 1:11), each = 5),
                   type = rep(c("AGD", "AGD", "AGD", "RTV", "RTV"), 6 + 11),
                   value = sample(1:100, 85),
                   size = rep(c("big", "small", "medium", "big", "medium"), 6 + 11))

years = data %>% arrange(year) %>% .$year %>% unique(.)
month = data %>% arrange(month) %>% .$month %>% unique(.)
type = data %>% arrange(type)%>% .$type %>% unique(.)
size = data %>% arrange(size) %>%.$size %>% unique(.)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("year","Year",choices = years,selected = 2018),
            selectInput("month","Month",choices = month,selected = 7),
            selectInput("type","Type",choices = type,selected = "AGD"),
            selectInput("size","Size",choices = size,selected = "big") 
    ),
    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #------- Initialize the Memory ----------
  selected_vals = reactiveValues(year = 2019,month = 7, type = "AGD", size = "big")

  #------ Whenever any of the inputs are changed, it only modifies the memory----
  observe({
    req(input$year,input$month,input$type,input$size)

    selected_vals$year <- input$year
    selected_vals$month <- input$month
    selected_vals$type <- input$type
    selected_vals$size <- input$size
  })

  #------ Update all UI elements using the values stored in memory ------
  observe({
    year <- data %>%
      select(year) %>%
      unique()

    updateSelectInput(session,"year",choices = year$year,selected = selected_vals$year)

  })

  observe({

      month <- data %>%
        filter(year == selected_vals$year) %>%
        select(month) %>%
        unique() %>%
        arrange()

      #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
      if (selected_vals$month %in% month$month) displayVal = selected_vals$month else displayVal = NULL

      updateSelectInput(session,"month",choices =  month$month,selected = displayVal)

  })

  observe({

    type <- data %>%
      filter(year == selected_vals$year,
             month == selected_vals$month) %>%
      select(type) %>%
      unique() %>%
      arrange()

    #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
    if (selected_vals$type %in% type$type) displayVal = selected_vals$type else displayVal = NULL

    updateSelectInput(session,"type",choices = type$type,selected = displayVal)

  })

  observe({

    size <- data %>%
      filter(year == selected_vals$year,
             month == selected_vals$month,
             type == selected_vals$type) %>%
      select(size) %>%
      unique() %>%
      arrange()

    #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
    if(selected_vals$size %in% size$size) displayVal = selected_vals$size else displayVal = NULL

    updateSelectInput(session,"size",choices = size$size,selected = displayVal)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Edit

As mentioned in the comment below there is a bug in the code. This is caused by the fact that then `displayVal = NULL` shiny sets the default value to display as the first element in he array. However we forget to store this in memory, `selected_vals`. The code below fixes this.

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

data <- data.frame(year = rep(c(rep(2018, 6), rep(2019, 11)), each = 5),
                   month = rep(c(7:12, 1:11), each = 5),
                   type = rep(c("AGD", "AGD", "AGD", "RTV", "RTV"), 6 + 11),
                   value = sample(1:100, 85),
                   size = rep(c("big", "small", "medium", "big", "medium"), 6 + 11))

years = data %>% arrange(year) %>% .$year %>% unique(.)
month = data %>% arrange(month) %>% .$month %>% unique(.)
type = data %>% arrange(type)%>% .$type %>% unique(.)
size = data %>% arrange(size) %>%.$size %>% unique(.)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("year","Year",choices = years,selected = 2018),
      selectInput("month","Month",choices = month,selected = 7),
      selectInput("type","Type",choices = type,selected = "AGD"),
      selectInput("size","Size",choices = size,selected = "big") 
    ),
    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #------- Initialize the Memory ----------
  selected_vals = reactiveValues(year = 2019,month = 7, type = "AGD", size = "big")

  #------ Whenever any of the inputs are changed, it only modifies the memory----
  observe({
    req(input$year,input$month,input$type,input$size)

    selected_vals$year <- input$year
    selected_vals$month <- input$month
    selected_vals$type <- input$type
    selected_vals$size <- input$size
  })

  #------ Update all UI elements using the values stored in memory ------
  observe({
    year <- data %>%
      select(year) %>%
      unique()

    updateSelectInput(session,"year",choices = year$year,selected = selected_vals$year)

  })

  observe({

    month <- data %>%
      filter(year == selected_vals$year) %>%
      select(month) %>%
      unique() %>%
      arrange()

    #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
    if (selected_vals$month %in% month$month){
      displayVal = selected_vals$month
    }else{
      displayVal = NULL
      selected_vals$month = month$month[1]
    } 

    updateSelectInput(session,"month",choices =  month$month,selected = displayVal)

  })

  observe({

    type <- data %>%
      filter(year == selected_vals$year,
             month == selected_vals$month) %>%
      select(type) %>%
      unique() %>%
      arrange()

    #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
    if (selected_vals$type %in% type$type){
      displayVal = selected_vals$type
    }else{
      displayVal = NULL
      selected_vals$type = tpye$type[1]
    }

    updateSelectInput(session,"type",choices = type$type,selected = displayVal)

  })

  observe({

    size <- data %>%
      filter(year == selected_vals$year,
             month == selected_vals$month,
             type == selected_vals$type) %>%
      select(size) %>%
      unique() %>%
      arrange()

    #Check if the value is in memory, if not return NULL (it defaults to the first element)
    if(selected_vals$size %in% size$size){
      displayVal = selected_vals$size
    } else{
      displayVal = NULL
      selected_vals$size = size$size[1]
    } 

    updateSelectInput(session,"size",choices = size$size,selected = displayVal)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution - I'll test it. I found one case when this solution does not work (when I change `month` to `12` and then change `year` to `2019` then values of `type` and `size` disappear). Do you know why something like this happens?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Marta. Yes, this bug does exist, I made the changes to fix this.